# How to add Peek&Pop to a segue not assigned to a button

Tags: objective-c, iphone, peek-pop

I have a segue that is not assigned to any button in the interface builder, 
but I do call a `[performSegue segueWithIdentifier@""]` when tapping in dynamic created button.

Is there a way to enable the `peek&pop` on those dynamic created buttons?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need implement methods of UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate.
See details [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/3d-touch-peek-and-pop.html)